# update to rails 3 on ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

Hopefully this is an easy one - I'm trying to install rails on my netbook. I can#'t seem to get it to update to rails 3 (seems stuck on 2.3.5). Here's some terminal output to show you what I mean...

```
mike@Ubuntu-Netbook:~$ rails -v
Rails 2.3.5
mike@Ubuntu-Netbook:~$ gem update rails
Updating installed gems
Nothing to update
mike@Ubuntu-Netbook:~$ sudo gem install rails
[sudo] password for mike: 
Successfully installed rails-3.1.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.1.0...
file 'lib' not found
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.1.0...
file 'lib' not found
mike@Ubuntu-Netbook:~$ rails -v
Rails 2.3.5
```

See? Stuck at 2.3.5! I have done a whole bunch of rails installs on other machines and never had this problem before - what am I missing?

The 2.3.5 install is completely working.

EDIT: I did not get an answer to this question. I got around it by investigating rvm and installing that way instead.

Comment: I think you should uninstall rails 2.3.5 gem (`gem uninstall rails -v2.3.5`)

Comment: Thanks man. I am going to try this tonight - I decided to check out RVM based on what the below guys were saying, and since I did that I've had nothing but problems so time to roll back i think!

Answer (score 2):

Are you using bundler? Are you in an rvm gemset?

If you're using the latter, once you sudo, you're in a different user's rvm install, so installation won't be the same. If you're using bundler and have locked rails to 2.3.5, that's what it'll be regardless whether you run **gem update** or not.

If you can answer the above two questions, we can probably narrow down your issue.

Comment: Definitely looks like you're using RVM here. By doing `sudo gem install` you install the gem onto the system. The `rails` command therefore will access the RVM one and not the system one.

Comment: Hi guys, I was following this guide; https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RubyOnRails#Get_Ruby . I just followed it again from scratch and now it works, dont' know what I missed the firtst time!